# Where is my principal place of business UK based?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, corporation, incorporating

I am in the process of setting up a company and trying to research everything before making the first step.  Though I do not live there, I intend to register the company at my parent's address so that I can receive mail there long term.  From my reading online,  this registered address can be anywhere, even an accountant's address.

When looking into what I would have to do to set up corporation tax, I noticed that I would need a principal place of business. I live in a rented accommodation and I believe that I would not be able use my landlord's address.  I will be doing most of my work in google campus (internet cafe).

Where should I/will I be able to set up my principal place of business?

Comment: If you live in rented accomodation then that is your address. Be aware that any mail you receive to your registered address is legally delivered to you, so the address of the company must be one that you visit regularly and often.

Answer (score 7):

There are many options when it comes to choosing a registered office address. I personally used one of the many companies that offer a "Registered office Service" so that I had a Central London address for my company and then paid to have any mail forwarded to me.

Type "registered office services uk" in google search and you will see a list of the many companies that offer this service.

Accountants also offer this service, but from my past experience they charge a lot for it, so worth comparing the online services fees with your accountants to see which offers best value.